# Pyomo: Implicitly replacing the Component attribute

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

**I am trying to solve this problem in Pyomo. What I have done is like this：**

[image]

```
model = AbstractModel()
model.Tom=Param(initialize=20100)
model.Peter=Var(domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.Gary =Var(domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.Nina=Var(domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.Samir=Var(domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.Linda=Var(domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.Bob=Var(domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.Y=Var(within=Binary)
model.M=Param(initialize=1000)

model.Cons_Peter = Constraint(expr=model.Peter-5000 >= model.Tom)
model.Cons_Nina = Constraint(expr=model.Nina-5000 >= model.Tom)
model.Cons_Samir = Constraint(expr=model.Samir-5000 >= model.Tom)

def Cons_Gary(model):
    return (model.Tom+model.Peter) <= model.Gary
model.Cons_Gary = Constraint(rule=Cons_Gary)

def Sum_1(model):
    return (model.Nina+model.Samir)>=2*(model.Tom+model.Peter)
model.Sum_1=Constraint(rule=Sum_1)

model.Cons_Bob1 = Constraint(expr=model.Bob+model.Y*model.M>= model.Peter)
model.Cons_Bob2 = Constraint(expr=model.Bob+(1-model.Y)*model.M>= model.Samir)

def Sum_2(model):
    return model.Bob+model.Peter>=60245
model.Sum_2=Constraint(rule=Sum_2)

model.Cons_Linda=Constraint(expr=model.Linda<= model.Tom+model.Bob)

def obj_salary(model):
     return model.Tom+model.Linda+model.Gary+model.Bob+model.Nina+model.Samir+model.Peter
model.salary= Objective(rule=obj_salary, sense=minimize)
```

> The error is WARNING: Implicitly replacing the Component attribute Tom
> (type=<class
> 'pyomo.core.base.param.SimpleParam'>) on block unknown with a new
> Component (type=<class 'pyomo.core.base.param.SimpleParam'>). This is
> usually indicative of a modelling error. To avoid this warning, use
> block.del_component() and block.add_component().

**I don't know why it can't run properly to get the minimum value of model.salary.
Can anyone help me with it?
Many thanks to your help!**

Answer (score 0):

Omg. I find the mistake finally.

It should be '**print(value(instance.profit))' not 'print(value(model.profit))'**.

What a stupid mistake I made.